# Java swing draw objects over other components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am trying to make a small paint program. I am drawing objects over a `JPanel` which is on top of `JFrame` (I am using Netbeans 6.9). I have some basic functionality like font, line and fillRectangle. I am using the standard method to draw which is to override `paintComponent()`.

```
class .... extends JPanel
{
@Override
void paintComponents(Graphics g)
{
.......
}
}
```

The problem is that when I draw a text,line over a region then it is drawn behind it rather than on top of it. Basically I want to draw objects on top of all other objects that have previously been drawn on the `JPanel`. I really do not want to switch to other types of layered pane. One very naive method will be to undo every object and paint them in reverse order (last one first).

Comment: Thanks David for your help. I did call paintComponent however the damned thing won't paint over its sibling. I guess glasspane sounds like a solution but will require too much overhead. Will see if I find any other way. By the way I rated your solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and do not forget to call `super.paintComponent(Graphics g);`

```
class .... extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);//honor paintComponent an call super to draw other components that were added to the JPanel
        .......
    }
}
```

You may also need to override `getPreferredSize(..)` of `JPanel` and return an appropriate size so the `JPanel` will be visible:

```
class .... extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(300,300);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Depending on what you are doing you may also want to have a look at the [GlassPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) which will allow you to set a transparent pane over the entire `JFrame` window and can be painted too, which will cause the graphics to be drawn above all others like so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I had the same problem and solved it by overriding **`paintChildren(Graphics g)`** instead of `paintComponent`.

As the [Oracle documentation](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html#smart) states, the order of execution for the three `paint` methods is:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g)
      protected void paintChildren(Graphics g)
```

So, `paintChildren(g)` is run last, which means whatever we draw inside it is drawn on top of all previously drawn components.